# Scikit-learn: Utilizing ElasticNet with GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am novice when it comes to Machine Learning, but I am very interested on this topic. I have a few questions so bear with me.

This is a time-series analysis.

I am using ElasticNet with GridSearchCV to figure out the best Hyperparameters for my model. I went through the steps with feature selection to reduce my features (I am using an f_regression at the basic <0.05 sig level). I am not using any test to figure out Multicollinearity, because I assume that elastic net would use the L1 ratio = 1 (Or close to it) to get around this issue. The parameter grids are listed below:

- l1_space = np.linspace(.30, .90, 30)
- alpha_space = np.logspace(-4, 1, 30)

However, the best parameters I keep getting are l1_space = 0.3 and alpha_space = 0.0001. Which defeats the purpose of using ElasticNet I assume? This gives me a really good adjusted R^2 and RMSE. However, when I change the parameter grids slightly, my metrics are horrible.

Its either the model is bad (Overfitting), or I just do not understand what is going on. I have read the documentations over and over again, but still am not understanding.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I figured out the issue. Since it is a time-series analysis, you cannot shuffle the data.